# Does Bhagvad Geeta have multiple versions?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

Does Bhagvad Geeta have multiple versions like many other scriptures?
Has anybody heard about it?

Comment: I don't think so because many saints gave commentaries on it so it was carefully preserved.

Comment: I don't think Bagadvad Gita by Sri Krishna has multiple versions. As Surya said, there are many commentaries for same Bagavad Gita. But, Apart from Bagavada Gita, there are other Gitas. [GITA, ITS VARIOUS KINDS](http://www.indianscriptures.com/vedic-knowledge/sacred-scriptures/gita/gita-its-various-kinds)